# <button> background image

Tags: html, css, image

I have got a little problem with setting a background image for `<button>`.

Here is the html I have got on site:

```
 <button id="rock" onClick="choose(1)">Rock</button>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
button {
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 2px solid #AD235E;
   border-radius: 100px;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
}

button #rock {
   background: url(img/rock.png) no-repeat;
}
```

I don't know why the button's background is still white.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Astonishing that no answer addresses or mentions the actual problem here.

The CSS selector `button #rock` says "give me an element with the id `rock` **inside** a `<button>` element", like this:

```html
<button>
    <span id="rock">This element is going to be affected.</span>
</button>
```

But what you wanted is a `<button>` element **with** the id `rock`. And the selector for that would be `button#rock` (note the missing space between *button* and *#rock*).

And as @Greg already mentioned: `#rock` is already specific enough to target the button and could be used on its own.

Answer (score 24):

For some odd reason, the width and height of the button have been reset. You need to specify them in the ID selector as well:

```
#rock {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(http://th07.deviantart.net/fs70/150/i/2013/012/c/6/rock_01_png___by_alzstock-d5r84up.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/NnXex/1/).

Answer (score 5):

You need to call CLASS in button

```
<button class="tim" id="rock" onClick="choose(1)">Rock</button>



<style>
.tim{
font-size: 18px;
border: 2px solid #AD235E;
border-radius: 100px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px; background-image: url(images/Sun.jpg);
}
</style>
```

Comment: giving id and button is complicated, class can be used for other buttons also

Comment: Either works, but id's are generally used for one of a kind elements, since their rules are difficult to outweigh. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2):

Replace
    button #rock
With
    #rock

No need for additional selector scope. You're using an id which is as specific as you can be.

JsBin example: http://jsbin.com/idobar/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS to this

```
button #rock {
    background: url('img/rock.png') no-repeat;
}
```

...provided that the image is in that place

Comment: I edited your answer to correct the selector. There shouldn't be a space between button and its ID.

Comment: You don't need the button part at all. It's just a performance hindrance.

Answer (score 0):

Delete "button" before # rock:

```
button #rock {
    background: url(img/rock.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Worked for me in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the white color you have to set the background-color to transparent:

```
button {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #AD235E;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: transparent; /* like this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need a button tag element?
because you can use instead an input type="button" element.

Then just link this CSS:

```css
  input[type="button"]{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  /*just this*/ background-image: url(https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/48d/marguerite-1372118.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 150px 150px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this way

```
<button> 
    <img height="100%" src="images/s.png"/>
</button>
```