# how to insert image in button background in javascript in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have to insert .png image in button background but it is not inserted in firefox extension in overlay.js/javascript file.

```
   var htmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
   var button = document.createElementNS(htmlns,"button");
   button.setAttribute("style", "background-image:in.png");    
   button.id = "btn1";
   documentElement.body.insertBefore(button, documentElement.body.firstChild);
   gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById("btn1").style.width = "45%";
   gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById("btn1").style.height = "78%";
```

Comment: Where is "in.png" located? In your add-on? On the server?

Comment: image is located in my add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for background-image is like that:

```
background-image: url(path/to/image)
```

As far as I know you can do something like that:

```
button.style.backgroundImage = "url(path/to/image)";
```

EDIT:
Maybe this will help:
[<button> background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461317/button-background-image)

Comment: I added link to other stack question, look at it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to fix your CSS, like @Sorprop already mentioned:

```
background-image: url(<url>)
```

See the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) documentation.

Next you need to use an absolute `URL` to point to your image. If you use a relative path, like in the question (`in.png`) this path will be resolved according to the base URI of the website, e.g. if injected into `https://www.google.com/` the browser would look for `https://www.google.com/in.png`, which is of course not present.

So if you register your package in `chrome.manifest` like:

```
content my-addon chrome/content
```

And your image is at `chrome/content/in.png`, you'll need to use:

```
background-image: url(chrome://my-addon/content/in.png);
```

You'll also need to allow web content access by setting the [`contentaccessible` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#contentaccessible).

```
content my-addon chrome/content contentaccessible=yes
```