# how to make a link to bootstrap modal through image with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make a link to bootstrap modal through clicking image.

I'm basically trying to adapt bootstrap [demo code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content) to ruby tags.

```
    <%= link_to 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#exampleModalLong' do %>
      <%= image_tag("https://i.imgur.com/qtVofCH.jpg", :class => "portfolio-image") %>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
             ... 
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

But this doesnt work. This makes it go to the top of the page, adding

> ?data-target=%23exampleModalLong&data-toggle=modal

to the url.

Edit1: Now i target the modal with just '#exampleModalLong':

```
      <%= link_to '#exampleModalLong', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' do %>
        <%= image_tag("https://i.imgur.com/qtVofCH.jpg", :class => "portfolio-image") %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        ...
      </div>
```

But it still won't work properly. Atleast it doesn't bring me back on the top of the page. And adds

> /#exampleModalLong

to the url.
I don't know why wont it trigger the modal div, when I target it through id.

Comment: you've got the modal div nested inside the anchor tag (link_to) but in the demo the modal div is outside?

Comment: I just have put it outside the tags, it still brings me ontop of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me [Modal bootstrap, image instead of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400223/modal-bootstrap-image-instead-of-button#20401918). Have you tried it? 
Be careful to change the id of the modal to have the same in the `data-target` attribute of your `<a>` tag and in the `id` of the `<div>` for your Modal window.

```
<!-- Button -->
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  <%= image_tag("https://i.imgur.com/qtVofCH.jpg") %>
</a>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185089/discussion-on-answer-by-cecilev-how-to-make-a-link-to-bootstrap-modal-through-im).