# Make a button with background

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, button

I want to make a html button with a flag as background. So in the folder images there's a picture called langnl.jpg. My code:

Html:

```
<button id="taal" onclick="changelangde()" >DE</button>
```

Css:

```
#taal{
background-image:images/langde.jpg; 
}
```

But it doesn't work, the button keeps just the default color. I've tried several options to link the image, but no one works. If I just only insert the image with an img-tag it works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<button> background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461317/button-background-image)

Comment: By the way, I also did try with '' around the url!

Comment: The path is right, I checked it with an img-tag as said.

Comment: i think you have to use <a> tag as you are using javascript function.

Comment: this may be the solution of your question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444894/how-to-set-background-image-in-submit-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
#taal{
 background: url('images/langde.jpg') no-repeat top left;
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 }
```

Comment: Mmmh, that changes something, but now the whole button is black??

Comment: does the image exists?

Comment: Yes it does, I will try another picture which i'm using already as a test.

Comment: Is the css in a different folder than your page. You know that images/lange.jpg will be relative to the css file location NOT to the document location, right? Or, maybe the image is black :)

Comment: Well, that works. But the image has to be scaled. I think at least. Because now I only can see the upper red color of the dutch flag.

Comment: Did that with background-size:100%; in the css file. THank you for your help!! It worked :)

Comment: It wasn't possible yet, but now I can @AnoopJoshi

Answer (score 0):

Change `images/langde.jpg;` to `url(images/langde.jpg);`

```
#taal{
background-image:url('images/langde.jpg'); 
background-size:cover;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#taal{
    background: url('images/langde.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

OR this:

```
#taal{
    background: url('images/langde.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

depends of what you want, you can see examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=initial).