# button with image and centered text as in the example

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create buttons with an image and a centered text on it, here a graphic example:
http://www.essenzialmenta.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ytbtn-1.png

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
`background: url(yourimage.png) center center no-repeat transparent;`
on the button with CSS to set a background image.

> There are already answered questions on Stackoverflow:
>
> `<input type="button">` Background: [How to add background image for input type="button"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738920/how-to-add-background-image-for-input-type-button)
> `<button>` Background: [<button> background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461317/button-background-image)

```css
.button{
        background: url(http://www.essenzialmenta.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ytbtn-1.png) center center no-repeat transparent;
        cursor:pointer;
        border: none;
        padding: 100px;
        }
```

```html
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Button" class="button"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but it seems odd the hover effect and the size of the button, though http://www.essenzialmenta.it/test-btn/

Comment: edit: decreased padding, but still hover problem
thank you very much!

Comment: hi, it's just the hover effect that does not work, it hides the img

Comment: can you replace that with a Zoom In hover effect? If yes, can you edit the css to do that?

Comment: Do you want it to Zoom in or make it bigger?

Comment: Edit: Here is it with zooming in smoothly http://jsfiddle.net/w08ps6r6/2/

Answer (score 0):

U may try,

> css

```
.button-image{
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  background: url(your-image.jpg) center center no-repeat transparent;
  border: none;
  display: block;
}
```

> html

```
<button class="button-image">Button Text</button>
```

you can change the height and width as per your requirement.